# XAMPP: never made a PHPMyAdmin login

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I installed XAMPP a couple of days ago. I uploaded a PHP file to C:/xampp/htdocs/ but the PHP isn't working. I went to the local host through Firefox and tried to use PHPMyAdmin to fix the problem, but I never made a login for that and I'm not given any option to sign up! I tried the username and password I gave when I set XAMPP up, but this didn't work. I searched the internet but could only find questions from people who have lost or need to reconfigure their logins. What's going on? Do you think I'm just misremembering the username/password I originally gave XAMPP (unlikely, but I suppose it's possible)?

And is any of this going to fix my PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there would be no set password after installation?

user:root, password:(blank)

Otherwise have you tried: user:root,  password: your mysql password?

Comment: Um... how do I find the "root"? The root server is Apache but I don't know what the root is otherwise...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite phrase that properly. I meant the straight out text "root"

Comment: (Meaning username: root and password: my mysql password for those in the future facing similar issues)